Save image to folder in project
Here is my code
public String addProducts() {
        try {
            filename = file.getSubmittedFileName();
            InputStream input;

            input = file.getInputStream();

            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Driver\\"+filename);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            product.setImage(filename);
            productsFacade.create(product);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProductsMB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "products";
    }

Im not very familar with FileOutputStream, my code so far work but I don't know to change the path of FileOutputStream to save the file in my project folder (without specify which disk my project in)
There is also another way I tried like this
  ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
        String uploadDirectory = servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/images/products");

        String filePath = uploadDirectory + "/" + filename;
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);



It work but It only save the file in dir folder and the image is gone when stop running the project

Im makeing a enterprise application in netbeans
here is where my folder tree
  -Web Pages
    -resources
     -images
      -products (where I want to save the file)
   -Source Package
    -com.mb
      -productsMB.java ( which my function is in)


The resources tree is for read only files. You need to choose a different directory to which you save things that you want to write. This is really nothing to do with your source tree either

Wherever you decide to save it, copy in one line as Files.copy(inputStream, Path.of(somepath))

Definitely the way

No need for a loop (which can introduce bugs, such as failing to close your OutputStream).  Use Files.copy(input, Path.of("D:\\Driver", filename)); or file.write("D:\\Driver\\" + filename); instead.
